# VBA multiple values in cell to filter worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro used to filter my worksheet, which uses the value in cell C4 of "FormResults" to filter the "Data" sheet. Im wondering if theres a way to have multiple values in that cell separated by a "," or blank space so the filter will pickup both?

If the value in C4 is "24", it filters the Data sheet on store 24 but if I have a C4 value of "24,25" or "24 25" is there a way for the autofilter to pickup both values before and after the use of commas or spaces so my Sheet filter would include both stores 24 and stores 25? Hope this makes sense.

```
Sub FilterDataByCellValue()

If Not IsEmpty(Sheets("FormResults").Range("C4").Value) Then
Sheets("Data").Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Sheets("FormResults").Cells(4, 3).Value ' Store Number Filter
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Consider creating an array from that cell's value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your filter should look for a list of values, you need to create an array and pass this as criteria. Creating an array from a string is simple, just use the `Split`-function. The good thing is that this works even if you have only one value, so you don't have to check if the filter cell contains a list or not.

```
Sub FilterDataByCellValue()
    With ThisWorkbook
        Dim filterCell As Range, filterList() As String
        Set filterCell = .Sheets("FormResults").Cells(4, 3)
    
        If IsEmpty(filterCell.Value) Then exit Sub
        filterList = Split(Replace(filterCell, " ", ","), ",")

        .Sheets("Data").Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=1, _ 
                       Criteria1:= filterList, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With

End Sub
```

Updated the code so that also blanks are used as separator - by simply replacing them with a comma. It doesn't matter if there are sequences with multiple blanks - this will create empty entries in the filter array that are ignored.

Comment: Ahh I see what you're getting at! The macro above only captures the last value though. If 24,26 is entered, it only filters on 26

Comment: Damn, cut and paste error from my test code - your need to provide the operator - updated the code.

Comment: That is a wicked solution, thank you Thomas!

Comment: Weird how one can see someone else forgetting the Operator but then forgetting to type `Field:=1` in his own test setup, d'oh! Gj with the quick and clean answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do:

Replace spaces with a comma (to get common delimiter)

`Split()` into array

Apply filter with array:

```
Sub FilterDataByCellValue()


If Not IsEmpty(Sheets("FormResults").Range("C4").Value) Then
    strCell = Sheets("FormResults").Range("C4").Text
    strCell = Replace(strCell, " ", ",")
    arFilter = Split(strCell, ",")
    Sheets("Data").Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1 _
        :=Array(arFilter), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution with multiple inputs in same cell,would be to use **TEXTSPLIT()** function, then assign each cell to a value (for example value_1 and value_2 below).
Then filter using the two values as multiple criterias.

```
=TEXTSPLIT(A1,",")
```

where A1 is : 1,2,3
Then, I have A2=1,B2=2,C2=3.

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=value_1, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=value_2
```

Comment: Where would C2's value be filtered in? If you need more than two values, it's better to go with an array like in FunThomas'/Viridian's answers.

Comment: Yes, you can always set Criteria1 = Array(value_1,value_2,value_3,...)